# WebDriver dismiss an Alert box

Tags: webdriver

how to dismiss a alert box by clicking "OK" button? I saw on WebDriver Google group that Simon is adding this feature. I am not sure whether this is supported or not.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
driver.findElement(By.id("updateButton")).click();
```

`//pop up with id "updateButton" opens`

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
//update is executed
alert.accept();
```

Comment: This is the proper way of doing it, especially post-circa-2012.  I don't see why this isn't checked as the answer to the question, because it should be.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at [issue 27 in the Google Code Issues List](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=27&q=alert&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary). Use the JavascriptExecutor to override the browser's alert:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.alert = function(msg){};");
```

It's a similar solution to handle confirmation dialogs.

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.confirm = function(msg){return true;};");
```

This is a pretty popular request so hopefully it'll get implemented soon. The downside to these approaches is that it's not easy to validate the text in the message. You may want to step down to Selenium to do that.

Comment: I have tried `((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.confirm = function(msg){return true;};");` but no luck. Seems like no one has a reliable workaround. I really hope they can get this done soon. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Double check that your driver refers to the correct page/frame. I've successfully run this so it must be something unique with your page, not the code.

Answer (score 4):

**C# code:**

```
IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
alert.Accept(); 
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
```

Answer (score 1):

Python code:

```
driver.switch_to_alert().accept()
```

See:

> site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py
>
> site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/alert.py