# java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not start Selenium session:

Tags: java, macos, selenium

In MacBook Pro, when I run the following Selenium, I am getting RuntimeException.

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;

public class Test {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
           DefaultSelenium selenium=new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444,"*firefox ","http://");
           selenium.start();
           selenium.open("http://google.co.in");
           selenium.windowMaximize();
           selenium.type("gbqfq", "selenium");
           selenium.click("gbqfb");
   }

}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not start Selenium session: Failed to start new browser session: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Firefox 3 could not be found in the path!
Please add the directory containing ''firefox-bin' or 'firefox'' to your PATH environment
variable, or explicitly specify a path to Firefox 3 like this:
*firefox3 /blah/blah/firefox-bin
       at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.start(DefaultSelenium.java:109)
       at Test.main(Test.java:8)
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: Failed to start new browser session: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Firefox 3 could not be found in the path!
Please add the directory containing ''firefox-bin' or 'firefox'' to your PATH environment
variable, or explicitly specify a path to Firefox 3 like this:
*firefox3 /blah/blah/firefox-bin
       at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrError(HttpCommandProcessor.java:112)
       at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.doCommand(HttpCommandProcessor.java:106)
       at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.getString(HttpCommandProcessor.java:275)
       at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.start(HttpCommandProcessor.java:237)
       at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.start(DefaultSelenium.java:100)
       ... 1 more
```

Please help me.. how to solve.

Comment: Why aren't you using the `WebDriver`? Selenium RC (`DefaultSelenium`) should not be used anymore if possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535950/difference-between-selenium-rc-and-webdriver

Comment: have you tried using another webdriver ? It's pretty clear that selenium is unable to find firefox. Also, the code is pretty out-dated, try considering updating it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the firefox profile path so that selenium can use it to instantiate the browser.

[OS X Firefox profile location](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder)

[Selenium w/ Firefox Profile 1](https://girliemangalo.wordpress.com/2009/02/05/creating-firefox-profile-for-your-selenium-rc-tests/)

[Selenium w/ Firefox Profile 2](https://girliemangalo.wordpress.com/2009/02/05/creating-firefox-profile-for-your-selenium-rc-tests/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

DefaultSelenium ds = new DefaultSelenium(new WebDriverCommandProcessor("http://:",new
    FirefoxDriver()));

// ds.start(); -- do not do this

ds.open("/pdm");

Answer (score 0):

Give Selenium Path as shown Below:

```
->DefaultSelenium  selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe", "http://");
```