# Why we don't need server in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

1. **Selenium RC** requires starting the server to kick of the execution of Selenium Automated RC test suites.
2. The Selenium server is the inter mediator between browser and Selenium RC because **Selenium RC** won’t make direct call to browser.
3. So we have to start Selenium server prior to start running Selenium RC test cases.
4. In case of **Selenium Web Driver**, it does not required to start Selenium Server for executing test scripts.
5. **Selenium Web Driver** makes the calls between browser & automation script.

Comment: The answer is given in the selenium website - http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp  and you can also refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535950/difference-between-selenium-rc-and-webdriver

Answer (score 4):

The Selenium server is the mediator between browser and Selenium RC because this RC won't make direct calls to the browser. We must therefore start Selenium server earlier to be running Selenium RC test cases. When you begin testing, Selenium RC Server "injects" a JavaScript program called Selenium Core into the browser. Once injected, Selenium Core will start receiving instructions relayed by the RC Server from your test program.

In case of Selenium WebDriver, it does not required to begin Server for executing check scripts. Whatever the commands issued in the code will be interpreted into Web service methods (JSON Wired Protocol) and the Remote Driver will receive the HTTP request (commands) and execute them in the browser then send back the responses. To give more information let say you have written test using Java (binding code) against Selenium API and that binding code is going to issue commands across WebDriver wire protocol - a REST-based web service that is able to interpret those commands. The driver server is just a little executable that runs each one of the drivers has this driver server that basically listens on a port on your local machine when you run your tests and it’s waiting for these commands to come in. And when these commands come in it interprets those commands and then automates the browser and then returns those results back.

Comment: why we are using a java script program, other than any scripting.

Comment: I may not be the right person to judge that. But if you ask me, i feel that JavaScript is the preferred language inside the browser to interact with HTML dom. This means that a Browser has JavaScript implementation in it and understands the JavaScript commands. Hence Java Script might have been used.

Comment: I hope this helps !