# Is selenium server required to create selenium automation using selenium client if i am not using selenium server standalone file?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I read this in Quora :

> Note: You should make sure if selenium-standalone-server.jar is needed
>   in your case. If all you need is to run a WebDriver test in local
>   machine please add java-client.jar. Its lightweight. Just for extra
>   information, selenium-standalone-server.jar is a bundled jar that
>   contains both API and selenium server. Selenium server is needed to
>   run older Selenium RC tests or to run WebDriver tests in remote
>   machines through Selenium Grid.

Assume that i am not using **selenium server standalone jar** file.
So to run tests in local do i need to use just **java-client jars** or do i need to add the **selenium server jar** as well?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that `selenium server` is *not* needed to run local `Selenium` tests, unless you are using `Selenium RC`.

More detail is given here: [Why we don't need server in Selenium Webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42562963/why-we-dont-need-server-in-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: How can I use selenium RC for local testing instead of webdriver? Is there a jar file for selenium RC?

Comment: The selenium grid download is here: https://selenium.dev/downloads/

Comment: https://techbeacon.com/app-dev-testing/selenium-30-release-testers-say-buh-bye-selenium-rc

Answer (score 0):

These are two distinct cases:

- **Running your *Test Suite* locally**: You can make use of language-specific client drivers. When using *Selenium Java Binding Art* you can use the jars published as [Selenium Java Client](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-java/)

> **Note**: Whether you need the Selenium Server or not depends on how you intend to use [Selenium-WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871). If your browser and tests will all run on the same machine, and your tests only use the *WebDriver APIs*, then you do not need to run the *Selenium-Server*; **WebDriver** will run the browser directly.

- **Running your *Test Suite* in a distributed network**: There can be some reasons though to use the **Selenium-Server** i.e. **Selenium Standalone Server**:

  - If you are using Selenium-Grid to distribute your tests over multiple machines or virtual machines (VMs).
  - If you want to connect to a remote machine that has a particular browser version that is not on your current machine.
  - If you are not using the *Java bindings art* (i.e. C#, Ruby, Python, Javascript) and would like to use *HtmlUnit Driver*.
  - If you are using *DefaultSelenium* (or the RemoteWebDriver implementation), you still need to start a *Selenium Server*. The best way is to download the **selenium-server-standalone.jar** from the [Selenium Downloads](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) page and use it.
  - You can also embed the *Selenium Server* into your own project, if you add the following dependency to your pom.xml:

    ```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    ```

    Now you can create a *Selenium Server* instance yourself and start it.

**Note** : **selenium-server** artifact has a dependency to the **servlet-api-3.1.0** artifact, which you should exclude, if your project will be run inside a web application container.

Comment: @automaticSoldier Any feedback on this answer?