# How to create Selenium objects?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I want to use following functions:
    get_xpath_count()
    get_css_count() and others available on
http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/selenium.html#selenium.get_xpath_count with selenium object.

But I am not able to create a selenium object to use these functions?
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing selenium web driver API and Selenium 1 / Selenium RC API: [what's the relationship between Selenium RC and WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619824/whats-the-relationship-between-selenium-rc-and-webdriver) is worth reading.

`get_xpath_count()` and `get_css_count()` are not a part of [selenium WebDriver API](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html).

You can actually simulate `get_xpath_count()` by calling `len()` on `find_elements_by_xpath()` method:

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org")

print len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li'))
```

`get_css_count()` could be implemented like this:

```
print len(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('li'))
```

Hope that helps.